# Example of a guarded object inside core java as defined in JCIP book

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

[JCIP](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=fv4tEfwgcjsC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=a+guarded+object+can+be+accessed&source=bl&ots=bD67kCA81A&sig=F1sTTWii6z0uFsFasCiDrcr9gNg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=F97yT83zCsSxrAfEsLW7CQ&ved=0CEwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=a%20guarded%20object%20can%20be%20accessed&f=false) defines Guarded objects as:

> **Guarded**. A guarded object can be accessed only with a specific lock held. Guarded objects include those that are encapsulated within 
>   other thread-safe objects and published objects that are known to be guarded by a specific lock.

Which can be cited as an example of such an object inside core Java ?

Comment: pretty much anything in the concurrent package... Say [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java.html) for example.

Comment: @assylias if you read the part in the link isn't CopyOnWriteArrayList an example of a shared thread safe object? I want to understand the distinction between "shared thread safe" object and "guarded" object through this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What comes to my mind immediately is the list held by the `SynchronizedList` instance returned by `Collections.synchronizedList()`. Here's a part of its source code:

```
static class SynchronizedList<E>
    extends SynchronizedCollection<E>
    implements List<E> {

    final List<E> list;

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        synchronized (mutex) {return list.equals(o);}
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        synchronized (mutex) {return list.hashCode();}
    }

    public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
        return list.listIterator(); // Must be manually synched by user
    }
```

The `list` object is not thread safe, but is guarded by the mutex. The object returned by `listIterator()` should be manually guarded by the same mutex (which is the synchronized list itself)

Comment: Haha - I had started writing that :-) +1

Comment: @JB Nizet why did they not guard the return with a lock like they did for hashcode() and equals()?